# How do I generate a number in a percentage range?

Tags: ruby

I am making a text adventure game and have to randomise the stats of my hero's enemies.

Is there a way to generate a random whole number from within a percentage range?
Like this: BaseHealth ± 10%, where BaseHealth is a variable.

Comment: Sure. Multiply and convert to an int and add/subtract.

Comment: But that would make a predefined number? I want to pick a random number between BaseHealth-10% and BaseHealth+10%. So if BaseHealth is 20, that would be any number between 18 and 22.

Comment: So you need a random number 0-5 (in this case) + 18, right? This is math and a random number, both of which are searchable :) See what you can come up with.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to know if there is something like rand(10±20%)

Comment: No, you need to use math.

Comment: Is `BaseHealth` a whole number?

Answer (score 2):

```
def randomize_value(value, percent)
  bottom = (value * (1 - percent / 100.0)).to_i
  up = (value * (1 + percent / 100.0)).to_i
  (bottom..up).to_a.sample
end

health = randomize_value(BaseHealth, 10)
```

This is assuming that health is to be integer.

Comment: While this is working correctly, creating a possibly huge array of consecutive integers feels ... wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If `BaseHealth` is integer,

```
def take_random base, percent
  d = (base * percent / 100.0).to_i
  base - d + rand(d * 2)
end

take_random(BaseHealth, 10)
```

or following Stefan's suggestion,

```
def take_random base, percent
  d = (base * percent / 100.0).to_i
  rand(base - d..base + d)
end

take_random(BaseHealth, 10)
```

Comment: or `rand(base-d..base+d)`

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you mean now

You can do this:

```
BaseHealth = ( rand(BaseHealth * 0.2) + BaseHealth*0.9 ).to_i
```

Comment: No, that will always give me 10% more. What I want is domething like this:
rand(#{BaseHealth.to_i} ± 10%)

Comment: No, if you think carefully, it won't.. because the random number is generated between 0% and 20%, then 10% (in effect) is deducted, which will give a random number between -10% and 10%, by the axioms of probability

Comment: I ran 10 times on 200: 184.0
181.0
180.0
216.0
193.0
191.0
194.0
212.0
203.0
193.0

Comment: and 10 times on 100: 91.0
96.0
104.0
106.0
98.0
97.0
100.0
90.0
93.0
96.0

Comment: @Marco Prins: This is still not quite right, as OP asked for whole numbers. Easy enough to fix (with a `.to_i` or `.round` on the result)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with some basic arithmetic:

```
TotalHealth = BaseHealth + (BaseHealth * (rand(21)-10)/100)
```

This will take the BaseHealth and multiply it by a random number `0..20` minus `10`, converted to a percent.

Assume BaseHealth = 20:

- If `rand` returns 17, you get `7/100 = .07` so `TotalHealth = 21.41`
- If `rand` returns 7, you get `-7/100 = -.07` so `TotalHealth = 18.6`

Comment: `rand(20)` will never be 20. So, you are not reaching `BaseHealth + 10%`. And you are doing integer math, so `TotalHealth` would be rather `21` than `21.41`.